# Why does calling a webapi post method throws error: no controller found?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have build a simple asp.net project with an webapi inside it. I have also an html page which send a POST request to webApi but it can't. It throws error

**No type was found that matches the controller named 'api'.**

Code:

WebApi:

```
namespace HimHer.Controllers
{
    public class ImagesController : ApiController
    {
        basicoperations bo = new basicoperations();

        public string Post([FromBody]Images imgs)
        {

            bo.Image = imgs.Image;
            bo.Story = imgs.Story;

            bool result = bo.insertImages(bo);

            return result == true ? "Success" : "Failed";
        }
    }

    public class Images
    {
        public int ID  {get; set;}
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Story { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ajax code:

```
function save()
{
  var images = {
      Image: imgUploader.value,
      Story: txtStory.value
  };

  var JsonImages = JSON.stringify(images);

  $.ajax
  ({
      url: '/api/Images',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: "application/json; charset= utf-8",
      data: JsonImages,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (results) {
          alert(results);
          $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      }
  });
}
```

**ImagesController** exists inside the Controllers folders.

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset= utf-8",`. Here you tell the ajax and the server that you are sending JSON. `var JsonImages = JSON.stringify(images);` here you convert your data into a single string, so that it isn't JSON any more. This second line I would think is unnecessary.

Comment: The above isn't directly related to your stated problem, but I suspect it might prove to be an issue later. Meanwhile try `api/Images` instead (without the leading `/`) to see if that helps with the actual path. And see in your network tab whether the full URL that's generated for the request is matches the correct one for your API.

Comment: Done. I also think you could have a problem with the response because you say `dataType: "json"`, but the API method returns a string not an object.

Comment: Your answer "This worked (...)" was deleted by the review process because it didn't look like an answer but rather like some additional info to your question. You may want to re-enter your answer and add some explanation so it clearly stands out as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `api/Images` instead (without the leading `/`) to see if that helps with the actual path. And then look in your network tab whether the full URL that's generated for the request is matches the correct one for your API.

Comment: thanks but actually this is working url: '/Images/post',

Still u gave me a lead

Comment: ah ok. It will be different depending on your routing config.

Comment: GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute
                ("Default", "{controller}/{id}",
                  new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

Comment: though the routing config haven't mentioned the action